# UIKit Closure to update Controller UI

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

How can I create a closure that allows you to modify the user interface of a controller?

Something like this::

```
// Presents controller
present(MyController()) {
    // Updates Controller
    $0.backgroundColor = .red
    $0.delegate = self
}
```

Instead of:

```
let controller = MyController()
// Updates Controller

controller.backgroundColor = .red
controller.delegate = self

// Presents controller
present(controller, animated: true)
```

I want to be able to do this because the code would look more organized and not have as many variables and constants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
extension UIViewController {
    func present(_ controller: UIViewController, completion: (UIViewController) -> Void) {
        present(controller, animated: true) {
            completion(controller)
        }
    }
}
```

Be wary of retain cycles. You may want to make the `controller` parameter optional to ensure it's held weakly. Or `[unowned controller]` next to the opening bracket of the `present(_:animated:)` completion block.

Also note it may look weird to the user to update the background colour of the view controller *after* the presentation animation has completed. You may want to take a different approach, such as:

```
extension UIViewController {
    func then(_ block: (Self) -> Void) -> Self {
        block(self)
        return self
    }
}
```

(This can be generalized to more than just `UIViewController`)

Usage:

```
MyController().then {
     $0.view.backgroundColor = .red
     $0.delegate = self
     self.present($0, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: The completion's parameter would also need to be optional. Also `present(_: animated:)` requires a non-optional `controller` so you'd have to conditionally unwrap it.

Comment: Thanks, is it safe to present a controller inside then?

Comment: Should be. As long as your custom `present` is called on the main thread.

Comment: How can I do so that I can access the properties of MyController and not just the UIViewController?

Comment: The closure is returning a UIViewController and not MyController

Comment: You can either cast the result, or you can change the `extension` to be on `MyController` and change the parameter types accordingly.